# Access Google+ Data in Google Contacts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-plus

If a contact has a public Google+ profile and this data appears in your Google Contacts, is it possible to access that data via Google Apps Script? If so, how?

For example, I add a contact with only a full name and an email address. That contact has a public Google+ profile that includes a phone number. Their phone number will show up in my Google Contacts (including a search from Google Contacts) but the following code will not return their phone number:

```
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
for (i in contacts) {
  phones = contacts[i].getPhones();
  for (j in phones) {
    Logger.log(phones[j].getPhoneNumber());
  }
}
```

How do I access the Google+ phone number via Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve this information. At least, not directly via Google Apps Script Contacts Services.

I also think that this should be possible. Please open an enhancement request on Apps Script [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: thank you for your response. My code does not clearly show it isn't possible. It just shows that the way I expected it to work did not.

Comment: Yes, that's the way it should work, but it doesn't and there's no other way.

Comment: I submitted it on the issue tracker, please vote: [Issue Tracker #1741](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1741)